# Is NUnit broken with Windows7 for C++/CLI?

Tags: nunit, c++-cli

NUnit is failing in C++/CLI with a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

I have tried my own freshly-created project, the C++/CLI sample included with NUnit and the one from CodeProject [How to use NUnit to test native C++ code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/NUnitNativeCPP.aspx) using Visual Studio 2008sp1 with NUnit 2.5.5 as well as 2.4.8. I installed 2.4.8 just on C:\ in case there was something weird about paths with spaces such as `Program Files (x86)`.

I have no problems with a C# sample using NUnit.

in NUnit GUI, all of these C++/CLI projects encounter the same problem, on attempting to open the projects.

I'd really like to use NUnit but for now have had to go back to standard Microsoft tests

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had what sounds like the same problem but via the NUnit console. It turned out that the NUnit console was JIT compiling to x64 rather than x86 and my C++/CLI assembly was x86. They need to be the same to work so I used the x86 specific version of the console. See http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.4.8.

Hope this helps,

Matt

Comment: yeah, something very annoying I have found people do often is, even when they release separate x86 and x64 kits, they compile the x86 kit with Platform=Any.